# node.js npm faster request? (for multiple requests)

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, npm, request

I'm wondering if there is a way to make requests faster (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

I currently have a program where I make 3 requests and it takes like 2.5s to do them all.  Any tips?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: parallel requests, your internet bandwidth, response time of your endpoint....